# ITunes Connect Localization - German, French

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add a German and French localization to the iTunes Connect Meta data. The app is in an editable state and I can choose from some given languages.

[image]

Also the docs mention French at the beginning of [the article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html), but then there are the same language choices.

The App is localized and has the "Localization" key in the info.plist.

I'm not seeing anything I can do about that (already tried to change my system language as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you scroll over that language page, can see `French` is waiting for you. That language pop-up is scrollable.

Comment: oh my god, wasted one hour with that problem... most ingenious answer, thank you taskiner!